# Angular 2 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to update a variable from my service to component. when i try to subscribe to it in the component i am getting error. can anyone help me please.

```
import {Injectable, } from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {MasterComponent} from '././master/master.component';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription"
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject" 

@Injectable() 
export class ConnectService
{
  showValues: string;
  public showValuesChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.showValues="1";
  }

  recvNotify(m) {
    buttonName = innervalue;
    console.log("ELSEinnervalue",buttonName);
    switch (buttonName) {
      case "0x01010000": 
        console.log('showValue==1');
        this.showValues = "1";
        this.showValuesChange.next(this.showValues);
        break;
      case "0x01020000":
        console.log('showValue==2');
        this.showValues = "2";   
        this.showValuesChange.next(this.showValues);
        $('#showValue').prop("value",2); 
        break;
      default:
        console.log('showValue==3');
        this.showValues = "3";  
        this.showValuesChange.next(this.showValues);
        break;
    }                      
  }
}
```

Component: Here i want to get the updated showValues from the service when ever there is a change in the value.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ConnectService} from '../connect.service';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'Master',
  templateUrl: './app/master/master.component.html',
  providers: [ConnectService]
})

export class MasterComponent {
  //showValue: any;
  public showValues: string;
  //show: any;

  constructor(
    public connectService: ConnectService,
    public _router: Router,
    public _subscription: Subscription){
    if(localStorage.getItem("clientStatus")=='connected'){     
      this.showValues = connectService.showValues;
      this._subscription = connectService.showValuesChange.subscribe((value) => {
        this.showValues=value;
        console.log("import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';",this.showValues);
      });

      this._router.navigate(['Master']);
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['Home']);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `recvNotify`?

Comment: `angular2/core', angular2/router, @angular/router` are you using multiple angular2 versions?

Comment: i have an other method to connect to the websocket, after getting the connection from there i am calling `client.onnotify = this.recvNotify; `

Comment: No i am not using. removed it thank you for correcting me. can you help me with the other issue please

Comment: Those module specifiers ending in the number 2 indicate you're using incredibly old beta version. I suggest you upgrade as you will have an incredibly hard time finding support. Note that upgrade will involve rewriting a non-trivial amount of the application and restructuring almost all of it.